Use Iterable<String> is not working with SOQL IN
I have a simple code with a SOQL query which uses IN method with the Iterable instance. However, Salesforce throws an error IN operator must be used with an iterable expression which is the exactly what I'm doing
List<Asset> getAssetsBySerialNumbers(
  Iterable<String> serialNumbersToCheck
) {
  return [
    SELECT SerialNumber
    FROM Asset
    WHERE SerialNumber IN :serialNumbersToCheck
  ];
}

Any idea on why it's not working?
I know I can wrap it into the new List<String>(serialNumbersToCheck) to fix it or use the exact iterable type in the arguments, but the message is still unclear why it's not working.

UPD
Thanks to comments, there is another question of this type Why I can't use Iterable<Id> in SOQL? . So  I'm not the first facing this issue. I haven't found the open Idea for this support so I opened a new one
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Qe3XiUAJ/allow-iterable-in-soql-native-bindings

This question is similar to: Why I can't use Iterable in SOQL?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@TusharJadav Note that things have changed since the linked question was written and answered.

Thanks @TusharJadav. It's similar actually. This question had an Idea reference, but seems it's removed, so I created a new one. Will be happy if you support it :) https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Qe3XiUAJ/allow-iterable-in-soql-native-bindings
